# Why did this "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet" image grow from 300 MB to 4 GB on Windows?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-8.0, windows-container

I recently migrated an ASP.NET Core running in a Windows container provided by Microsoft from .NET 7 to .NET 8.

The official default ASP.NET Core image is now 10 times bigger. Why?

```
> docker images
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet   8.0.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022   175b932722fc   8 weeks ago    4.36GB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet   7.0                                6a62cbd93ce2   3 months ago   393MB
```

Answer (score 4):

For Windows-based container images (otherwise you may be comparing Linux-based and Windows-based images) according to the **Nano Server 2022 amd64 Tags** table from [the Docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet):

| Tag | Dockerfile | Last Modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8.0.1-nanoserver-ltsc2022, 8.0-nanoserver-ltsc2022 | Dockerfile | 01/09/2024 |
| 7.0.15-nanoserver-ltsc2022, 7.0-nanoserver-ltsc2022, 7.0.15, **7.0** | Dockerfile | 01/09/2024 |
| 6.0.26-nanoserver-ltsc2022, 6.0-nanoserver-ltsc2022, 6.0.26, 6.0 | Dockerfile | 01/09/2024 |

7.0 was using [Nano Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-base-images#choosing-a-base-image) as base image:

> `Nano Server` is an ultralight Windows offering for new application development.

While you have switched to one using Windows Server Core 2022:

> `Server Core` is medium in size and a good option for "lifting and shifting" Windows Server apps.

Try using `8.0-nanoserver-ltsc2022` as base.

See also [Nano Server x Server Core x Server - Which base image is the right one for you?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/nano-server-x-server-core-x-server-which-base-image-is-the-right/ba-p/2835785) article.